# Undestanding why retraction turns the LES of relative homology groups to SES on pg.147 AT.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The following paragraph is written in Hatcher:

> [image]

But I do not understand this statement: "From this it follows that the boundary maps in the long exact sequence for $(X, A)$ are zero" According to Pg.115 in AT, I do not see where are the boundary maps, could anyone explain this statement in details for me, please?

Comment: The boundary maps here are the homomorphisms $H_n(X,A) \to H_{n-1}(A)$. If $A\to B\overset{0}\to C$ is exact, then so is $A\to B\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The "boundary maps" are the maps $\partial:H_n(X,A)\to H_{n-1}(A)$ in the long exact sequence of homology for the pair $(X,A)$.  They are so named because they are defined using the boundary map on the chain complexes (as described in the bottom half of page 116).  If you know that $i_*:H_{n-1}(A)\to H_{n-1}(X)$ is injective then exactness of the sequence tells you that $\operatorname{im}(\partial)=\ker(i_*)=0$ and so $\partial=0$.

Comment: I sure wish Hatcher had used $\delta$ instead of $\partial$ ...

Comment: @TedShifrin He uses $\delta$ for cohomology and $\partial$ for homology.

Comment: The connecting homomorphisms in long exact sequences are not, however,  boundary maps.